# Compiling and Linking to Visual Studio 2022 using OpenCV source code built as Win32 from CMake C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Dear ImGui in Visual Studio 2022. I'm new to C/C++ libraries and building in general, so I'm unsure if I'm doing anything right. ImGui uses 32-bit architecture and I've used Cmake gui to compile the source code as Win32. I think I have the compiled source code, but it seems to be different than downloading the pre-built libraries. [File Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOfs6.png). I've added the bin to PATH environmental variable, and in Visual Studio tried adding \include to Include Directories, \lib or \lib\Debug to Library Directories, and opencv_world460d.lib to Additional Dependencies. The program still runs, but it doesn't seem to include anything related to OpenCV in the #include files. I found a few .dll files in bin\Debug, but I'm not sure if I should bother with that. I think I could move the source code into the project, but I'm fairly certain that isn't the proper way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have built the project, but probably you didn't run the install target. Try running `cmake --build <build_dir> --config Release` and then `cmake --install <build_dir> --config Release`, where `<build_dir>` is a placeholder for the path to the build dir shown in the screenshot. The latter command probably requires admin privileges. Probably best to check the docs of the lib, if there's a step by step instruction for building & installing the whole thing.

Comment: I ran the install target, but I still don't think it is included in Visual Studio. Most of the examples that I've found use something along the lines of #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>. If I include would I use the same include statements?

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to use the correct path for include and Library Directories

Comment: "Included in Visual Studio"? If you want to include opencv in your own application, you could create it as a cmake project and use the package configuration scripts that should be installed alongside any dlls/import libs (`find_package()`) or you manually edit the Include directories and linked libraries of your "standard VS project". The fact that you're built & installed OpenCV once does not mean it's automatically available to any VS project on your machine.

Comment: I should've been more specific but I meant that I thought I edited Project Properties correctly, and the source files weren't showing up when I made the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run the install target:

> You may have built the project, but probably you didn't run the install target. Try running cmake --build <build_dir> --config Release and then cmake --install <build_dir> --config Release, where <build_dir> is a placeholder for the path to the build dir shown in the screenshot. The latter command probably requires admin privileges. Probably best to check the docs of the lib, if there's a step by step instruction for building & installing the whole thing. –
> fabian

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.  Just a reminder :)